# Symfony best pratice

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony 3.3 and I want to know what is the best practice for these cases :

on render() for display template

```
- folder:view.html.twig
- folder/view.html.twig
- @folder...
```

on getRepository()

```
- 'AppBundle:EntityName'
- Entityname::class
```

on formtype

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => EntityName::class
));
```

or

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\EntityName'
));
```

on formtype like entitytype

```
   ->add(
        'words',
        EntityType::class,
        array(
            'class'        => Word::class,
        )
    )
```

or

```
   ->add(
        'words',
        EntityType::class,
        array(
            'class'        => 'AppBundle\Entity\Word',
        )
    )
```

On controller Action()

```
newAction(EntityManagerInterface $em)
```

or

```
    public function newAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }
```

I have read the best practice on symfony website but I have not see those informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 15-nov-2017**:  Symfony best practices have been updated -> https://symfony.com/doc/master/best_practices/index.html.

---

Use normal path (ie. `folder/view.html.twig`) or `@` to refer to twig template. The [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html) says :

> In the past, Symfony used a different syntax to refer to templates. This format, which uses colons (:) to separate each template path section, is less consistent and has worse performance than the Twig syntax.

Use `::class` notation each time it's possible. It's more natural and easier to maintain, write and read.

For the last one, it really depends on your context but IMO it's better to use repository class and avoid using the entity manager directly in your controller.

Regarding dependency injection in controller, the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#controllers-are-registered-as-services) says :

> In general, the new best practice is to use normal constructor dependency injection (or "action" injection in controllers) instead of fetching public services via $this->get() (though that does still work).

Comment: just out of curiosity, how do you use a repository class in your controller *without* using the entity manager?

Comment: @DevDonkey just as a service? https://matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/

Comment: yeah but a repository is always going to use the entity manager

Comment: Yes but as an implementation detail ;-) Client of the repository would not know if you are using doctrine / pdo or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

**"Extraction is better than abstraction"**

That's why I choose:

- Class names defined by operator `::` like `EntityName :: class`
- Physical paths like `Folder/view.html`
- Dependency Injection rather than the `Service locator` pattern or deep diving for a dependency.

For example: I can rely on the IDE to not let me go wrong in the definition of an absolute class name. I can use native functions for validation and path transformations.

Generalizing. I always try to avoid domain dependencies other than native.

This is my practice and it's not related only to the great Symfony.